# jquery attached event with class execute more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some div`s with same class say:

```
<div id="1" class="same">..</div>
<div id="2" class="same">..</div>
<div id="3" class="same">..</div>
```

I attach eventhandler all div :

```
$(".same").live({mouseenter : function{ /*code*/ },mouseout: function{ /*code*/ }})
```

Now my problem is when mouseenters to div `(id="1")` , the code for mouseenter function will executes 3 time may be because there are 3 divs with `class="same"` but i want it to execute  only one time and without attaching the events with ids. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo showing your problem. The behaviour you describe should not happen, so you must have an error somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have an example of this happening? That code should only fire once, unless all the 3 divs are on top of each other in the document.

Comment: i wonder what's happening inside your handlers.. can we take a look?

Comment: I don't think it executes three time.. it should fire only once. >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WD2E7/ <<

Comment: You are probably setting the event handler three times. Are you running that jquery command inside a loop? Or inside a function you call multiple times?

Comment: Are the `<div>`'s nested and you're `mouseenter`ing on the inner-most one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event does not bind for three times. But you might get mouse enter of one div when you move to next div you get mouse out of this dive and mouseenter of other div.

Moving in to first div and then to second fires three events

1. mouseenter of first div
2. mouseout of first div
3. mouseenter of second div

   [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccHjQ/3/)

I have made a little change by adding parenthesis after keyword function as script was not executing for me.

Before

```
$(".same").live({mouseenter : function{ /*code*/ },mouseout: function{ /*code*/ }})
```

After

```
$(".same").live({mouseenter : function(){ /*code*/ },mouseout: function(){ /*code*/ }})
```

You could execute this code to see what is happening

```
 $(".same").live(
    {
     mouseenter : 
     function()
     { 
         alert(" mouseenter >>Current Div ID = "+ this.id);
     },
     mouseout: 
     function()
     { 
         alert("mouseout >>Current Div ID = "+ this.id);
     }
    }
);​
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but this should be helpful:

```
busy = false;
$(".same").live(
{mouseenter : function ()
    {
        if(busy==false){busy = true; /*code*/}
    },
 mouseout: function ()
    {
        if(busy==true){/*code*/ busy = false;}
    }
});
```